# How to display FluentNHiberante Exceptions or SQL Exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate

I use FluentNHibernate and SQLite. Often I get Exception in the fluent configuration due to some problem with my Domain classes. But VS only pops up an InvalidOperationException, with no info about what class or method is the problem.

What I need to do to get displayed more useful exception info in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually have a try catch around the creation of my session factory and I'll log and display the exception information to the log file/console.  Use the exception .ToString method.  This should give you more detail.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Write to console, display, etc the exception 
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```